# How to use Laravel 5.4 validator at web service for mobile application

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel, validation

I have a problem with Laravel 5.4 validator which is I'm trying to validate data comes from a mobile application but when validator fails it redirect to the home page. I need to prevent this redirect and return a json response with validation errors messages
Here's my route.php code

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {
   Route::post('/userSignUp', [
       'uses' => 'UserController@userSignUp', 
       'as'   => 'userSingUp'
   ]);
});
```

And this is my controller code

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function userSignUp(Request $request){
        $fullName   = $request->input('fullName');
        $email      = $request->input('email');
        $phone      = $request->input('phone');
        $password   = $request->input('password');
        $userType   = $request->input('userType');
        $profilePic = $request->input('profilePic');


        $validator = $this->validate($request, [
                    'fullName' => 'required|max:255',
                    'email'    => 'required|email',
                    'phone'    => 'required'
                ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {    
            return response()->json($validator->messages(), 200);
        }
    }
}
```

So can anyone help me solving this issue I need to use a laravel 5.4 validator in a web service for a mobile application so I need to prevent the validator redirecting as it does in the above code it redirecting to home page when validation is failed
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the validation fails when you call `$this->validate($request,$rules)` laravel will throw an exception and a failed validation response will be sent back by this method define in `Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests` :

```
/**
 * Create the response for when a request fails validation.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  array  $errors
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
protected function buildFailedValidationResponse(Request $request, array $errors)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return new JsonResponse($errors, 422);
    }

    return redirect()->to($this->getRedirectUrl())
                    ->withInput($request->input())
                    ->withErrors($errors, $this->errorBag());
}
```

So it seems that Laravel does handle that by checking `$request->expectsJson()` so you need to specify the `Accept` header in you request to JSON, then a JSON formatted response with code `422` will be returned.

Comment: I need to know where to add this function

Comment: You don't need to add this function, it is part of laravel code, I'm showing you how failed validation is handled. What you need to do is specify that you want JSON response in the request that you are sending. by setting the `Accept` header.

Comment: If you allow me I need to know how to use `if($validator->fails())` cause I'm trying to use it but the code stops before it and return a json response, I need to use it to add attributes to the response

Comment: I'm not really sure about that, since all the error messages are returned I never needed a custom response, but I think you would have to do the validation yourself instead of using the validate method in the controller.

Comment: I did, I used validator class to customize my manual validation.

Answer (score 0):

```
return response()
->json(['name' => 'Abigail', 'state' => 'CA'])
->withCallback($request->input('callback'));
```

from the official doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#json-responses

And maybe try to make your validation in your model directly

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
   private $rules = array(
      'fullName' => 'required|max:255',
      'email'    => 'required|email',
      'phone'    => 'required|numeric'
   );


  public function validate($data)
  {
    // make a new validator object
    $v = Validator::make($data, $this->rules);
    // return the result
    return $v->passes();
  }
}
```

and in your controller you can make

```
$new = Input::all();
$u = new User();
if ($b->validate($new))
{

}
else
{

}
```

Comment: You mean `$u->validate($new))` not `$b->validate($new))`
I'm tried to do it but I got that error **Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::validate()**

Comment: yep it's $u sorry , for Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::validate() in your controller add the namespace of your model in your case on top it's use 'App\User'